# Show UIActivityIndicatorView when switching view controllers

Tags: ios, uiactivityindicatorview

I have a view controller that segues to a second view controller which loads several images but it hangs for a second or two before seguing from the first VC to the second. I am trying to add a UIActivityIndicatorView so that the user doesn't think the app is frozen (which is currently what it feels like). However I can't seem to get it to work properly and all of the examples I've seen are using a web view or are accessing some kind of data from a server whereas I'm loading images that are stored in the app.

I have some code below to show what I have attempted.

.h file

```
@interface SecondViewController: UIViewController
@property (strong, nonatomic) UIActivityIndicatorView *indicator;
```

.m file

```
-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    self.indicator = [[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc] initWithActivityIndicatorStyle:UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleGray];

    self.indicator.center = CGPointMake(160, 240);

    [self.view addSubview:self.indicator];

    //Loading a lot of images in a for loop.
    //The images are attached to buttons which the user can press to bring up
    //an exploded view in a different controller with additional information
    [self.indicator startAnimating];
    for{....}
    [self.indicator stopAnimating];
}
```

I have tried also using `dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0)` immediately after the call to `[self.indicator startAnimating]` but all that happened was that the view controller loaded instantly and the images/buttons never loaded at all.

How can I get rid of the delay when the user clicks the "next" button on the first view controller? The app hangs on the first VC for about a second or two then finally loads the second view controller with all the images/buttons. Do I need to add the `UIActivityIndicatorView` to the first view controller instead or am I going about this completely the wrong way? I'm open to any and all methods to get this done, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to call the initialization code and stopAnimating in the next run loop. One easy thing you can do is the following:

```
-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    self.indicator = [[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc] initWithActivityIndicatorStyle:UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleGray];
    self.indicator.center = CGPointMake(160, 240);

    [self.view addSubview:self.indicator];

    //Loading a lot of images in a for loop.
    //The images are attached to buttons which the user can press to bring up
    //an exploded view in a different controller with additional information
    [self.indicator startAnimating];
    [self performSelector:@selector(loadUI) withObject:nil afterDelay:0.01];
}

-(void) loadUI {
    for{....}
    [self.indicator stopAnimating];
}
```

Of course there are other ways to run loadUI in the next run loop (such as using a timer).

Comment: This way will hang the main thread, and the ui will be irresponsible. You should loadUI in background thread and dispatch to main thread to update UI.

Comment: The UI will blocked until the "for{...}" part is finished, but the activity indicator will be animating correctly. The implementation really depends on the design: whether you would like the user to be able to interact with the UI before the "for{...}" initialization is finished. If loadUI is called in background thread and dispatched to main thread, the user will be able to interact with the UI before "for{...}" is done, and that may not be what the author wants.

Comment: The user doesn't need to have any interaction with the app until the image/buttons load. I want the app to show the indicator spinning until the images are all loaded.

Comment: For any case you shouldn't block the main thread. If you wouldn't like the user to be able to interact with the UI, simply set view.userInteraction = NO;.

Comment: @subchap code will work in that case. But if you rotate the device while loading UI, you will see it is very bad for the user.

Comment: This is not really "blocking" the main thread. It's just using the main thread to do some UI initialization work. I assume that "for{...}" part has to be done in the main thread, and is not going to take long time to finish. However, if you are loading images from the web, and doing some other work that should be done in the background, then I think @sahara108's suggestions is good, and you should restructure your code.